# filtering through array of object not working react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of products that looks like this
[image]
I am trying to filter out products with a specific category,

```
 const filteredTrendingProducts = products.filter(
      (item) => item.data.category === "Kids"
    );

 setTrendingProducts(filteredTrendingProducts);
```

this returns and empty object yet I can clearly see  in the array there is a data key and in data there is category.Why is the object returning empty?

Comment: can you try setTrendingProducts(prev => prev.filter((item) => item.data.category === "Kids"))

Comment: can you try a console.log of filteredTrendingProducts after the filter? Does this return null ?

Comment: Please include some more relavent code so that the community members can better understand the problem, nor they can only give guess  instead of answers

Comment: [Working fine for me!](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-firefly-ld4ecr?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You'll need to provide more context/code for us to see what the real issue is, such as sharing where you're logging `products` and how it's being populated. It could be an issue where you're trying to access a state value that hasn't been set yet, or maybe an issue with closures, but we can't tell without seeing more code.

Comment: I realise the issue was not with the logic,it was how I was accessing the data.I was trying to render the trendingproduct in page.The problem was in the how I was retrieving the products after fetching them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your logic is correct.** Perhaps your program's lifecycle is wrong.

When you have the wrong lifecycle, components might not have the correct data and still load. Because of this, perhaps, the data comes empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an anwer
but try putting console logs to debug the filter function

```
const filteredTrendingProducts = products.filter(
      (item) => {
        console.log("item.data", item.data);
        console.log("item.data.category", item.data.category);
        console.log(item.data.category === "Kids", item.data.category == "Kids");
        return item.data.category === "Kids"
      }
    );
```